# Как создать метод очистки приватных переменных?

Tags: php, функции, классы, методы

```
<?php

class Num_1{
private $a;
private $b;
public function setNum1($a){
    $this->a = $a;
}
public function setNum2($b){
    $this->b = $b;
}
public function getNum1(){
    return $this->a;
}
public function getNum2(){
    return $this->b;
}

public function multiply(){
    return $this->getNum1() * $this->getNum2();
}
public function del(){
    return $this->getNum1() / $this->getNum2();
}
public function sum(){
    return $this->getNum1() + $this->getNum2();
}
public function getfunc(){
    return $this->getNum1();
}
//Очистка
public function delet(){
    $this->getNum1()
   return unset(getNum1());
}
}
$Num_cl = new Num_1;
$Num_cl->setNum1(10);
$Num_cl->setNum2(5);

echo  $Num_cl->multiply() . "<br>";
echo  $Num_cl->sum() . "<br>";
echo  $Num_cl->del() . "<br>";
echo  $Num_cl->getfunc() . "<br>";
echo  $Num_cl->delet() . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: `$this->a = null`? Может будет проще еще один объект создать?

Comment: $this->setNum1(null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно все сделать через один метод-сеттер `set`, ну раз уж человеку `нннада`.. :)

```php
<?php
class Num_1 {
    private $a;
    private $b;
    private $c;
    private $d;
    // ....

    /**
    * Массовое присвоение внутренним переменным их значений
    * @param array $varsList ассоциативный массив ( key => value )
    * @return integer кол-во переменных которым было присвоено новое значение
    */
    public function setVars( $varsList = [] ) {
        $result = 0;
        foreach( $varsList as $key => $value ) {
            if ( trim( $key ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $key ) ) {
                $this->$key = $value;
                $result++;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
    * Массовая очистка у внутренних переменных их значений
    * @param array $varsList массив имен переменных
    * @return integer кол-во переменных которые были очищены
    */
    public function eraseVars( $varsList = [] ) {
        $list = [];
        foreach( $varsList as $varName ) {
            $list[ $varName ] = null;
        }
        return $this->setVars( $list );
    }

    /**
    * Очистка значения внутренней переменной
    * @param string $varName имя внутренней переменной
    * @return boolean 
    */
    public function eraseVar( $varName ) {
        return $this->setVar( $varName, null );
    }

    /**
    * Присвоение значения внутренней переменной
    * @param string $varName имя внутренней переменной
    * @param mixed $varValue значение внутренней переменной
    * @return boolean 
    */
    public function setVar( $varName, $varValue ) {
        $result = false;
        if ( !is_null( $varName ) && trim( $varName ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $varName ) ) {
            $this->$varName = $varValue;
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
    * Получение значения внутренней переменной
    * @param string $varName имя внутренней переменной
    * @param mixed $defaultValue значение которое будет вернуто по-умолчанию, если переменной не существует
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getVar( $varName, $defaultValue = null ) {
        $result = $defaultValue;
        if ( !is_null( $varName ) && trim( $varName ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $varName ) ) {
            $result = $this->$varName;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
    * Возврат ассоциативного массива значений вида ( key => value ) указанных внутренних переменных
    * @param array $varsList массив имен переменных
    * @return []
    */
    public function getVars( $varsList = [] ) {
        $result = [];
        foreach( $varsList as $varName ) {
            $result[ $varName ] = $this->getVar( $varName );
        }
        return $result;
    }
}


$Num_cl = new Num_1();
$Num_cl->setVars(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4]);
var_dump( $Num_cl->getVars(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) );
$Num_cl->eraseVars(['b', 'c']);
var_dump( $Num_cl->getVars(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) );
```

Результаты

```
array(4) {
 'a' => int(1), 
 'b' => int(2), 
 'c' => int(3),
 'd' => int(4) 
} 

array(4) { 
 'a' => int(1),
 'b' => NULL, 
 'c' => NULL,
 'd' => int(4) 
}
```